# How to compose a combine publisher that emits the last-emitted value to its 2nd subscriber

Tags: swift, combine

I'm trying to compose a publisher, that, when a subsequent subscriber connects to it, emits the last emitted value immediately to that subscriber, and then continues to emit future values to all connected subscribers.

**Q:** Is there a way to do this **without writing a publisher from scratch**, and only by composing built-in publishers? I might be missing something here.

So, if we had a publisher counting every second:

```
let counter = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
                   .autoconnect()
                   .scan(0, { v, _ in v + 1 })


let sharedPublisher = // ??? something with counter publisher above

sharedPublisher.sink { print("A: ", $0 }.store(in: &bag)

// after 2.5 seconds
sharedPublisher.sink { print("B: ", $0 }.store(in: &bag)
```

The output would be:

```
A: 1 // at t=1 sec
A: 2 // at t=2
B: 2 // at t=2.5
A: 3 // at t=3
B: 3 // at t=3
```

---

Initially, naively, I thought I could just use a `.share` and a `.buffer`:

```
let sharedPublisher = counter
                  .share()
                  .buffer(size: 1, prefetch: .byRequest, whenFull: .dropOldest)
```

but of course, that doesn't work since `buffer` only buffers if the downstream isn't ready to accept values, which isn't the case here.
Maybe something with `Record`/`Record.Recording`?

Comment: The publisher that hands a new subscriber its most recent value is a CurrentValueSubject.

Comment: @matt, I thought `CurrentValueSubject` always gives the initially provided value in its init. It actually gives the last emitted? EDIT: you're right! Could you write an answer on how to hook it up to get the output above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A publisher that can be shared out (because it's a class, not a struct) and that immediately hands to any new subscriber its most recent value is a CurrentValueSubject. So, for example, this is not quite what you were doing, but it demonstrates the point:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer : Timer?
    let sub = CurrentValueSubject<Int,Never>(0)
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
            self.sub.value += 1
        }
        delay(0.5) {
            self.sub.sink { print("A:", $0) }.store(in: &self.storage)
        }
        delay(2.5) {
            self.sub.sink { print("B:", $0) }.store(in: &self.storage)
        }
    }
}
```

That outputs

```
A: 0
A: 1
A: 2
B: 2
A: 3
B: 3
```

which seems to be exactly the effect you're after.

The cool thing is that a Subject can also be an operator (via a publisher's `.subscribe` method) so it can exist downstream of something else while maintaining this behavior. The only trick is that you have to retain the Subject (which you can do because the `.subscribe` call yields an AnyCancellable). So now I can do it *your* way, i.e. starting with a timer publisher:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let counter = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
                           .autoconnect()
                           .scan(0, { v, _ in v + 1 })
        let sub = CurrentValueSubject<Int,Never>(0)
        counter.subscribe(sub).store(in: &self.storage)
        delay(0.5) {
            sub.sink { print("A:", $0) }.store(in: &self.storage)
        }
        delay(2.5) {
            sub.sink { print("B:", $0) }.store(in: &self.storage)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool... I had to add `.dropFirst()` to drop it's initial (which in my case is unknown/arbitrary) value that a first subscriber was getting, but otherwise it works!

Comment: Wait, there's more! Hang on a tic.

Comment: Okay, finished! :)

Comment: Still struggling to turn it into a cleanly composed operator, something like `somePublisher.shareLast()` because of the need to store the subscription