# Swift Combine: direct output of one Publisher to the input of another

Tags: ios, swift, combine, publisher

Consider the following synthetic scenario:

```
import Combine

let publisher1 = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>().eraseToAnyPublisher()
let publisher2 = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()


publisher1.sink { value in
    publisher2.send(value)
}
```

We have 2 publishers, I'd like to propagate any value of the `publisher1` to the `publisher2`. The code I've shown does the job, but I'm interested whether there is a cleaner, declarative approach to this.

Note: both `publisher1` and `publisher2` are of the same type.

**Details on the problem**

`publisher2` is a part of the API that is exposed by the "core" class. The "core" class has a "has a" relationship to a "child" class which in turn has a `publisher1` as it's API.

Over the lifetime of the "core" class, the "child" class can be allocated and deallocated multiple times. This should be transparent to the subscribers of the "core" class which won't need to subscribe to the `publisher2`.

**Code:**

```
import UIKit
import Combine


class ChildClass {
    let publisher1 = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>().eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

class CoreClass {
    let publisher2 = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

    private var childClass: ChildClass?

    init() {
        allocateChildClass()
    }

    func allocateChildClass() {
        let child = ChildClass()
        childClass = child
        // Any way to simplify this?
        child.publisher1.sink { value in
            publisher2.send(value)
        }
    }

    func deallocateChildClass() {
        childClass = nil
    }
}


class Client {
    let core = CoreClass()

    init() {
        // Doesn't care about allocating or deallocating of the ChildClass
        core.publisher2.sink { value in
            print(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to subscribe one publisher to another doesn't work:

```
publisher2
    .subscribe(publisher1)
```

> No exact matches in call to instance method 'subscribe'

[image]

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to achieve? Without more context, this seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Is `publisher2` or can you create another publisher that "shadows" `publisher1`? Does `publisher2` also emit values on its own?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, updated my questions with a bit more context on the problem.

Comment: A Subject can be a subscriber. There is no need for a sink and no need to call `send`. That sort of thing is totally contrary to the spirit of Combine.

Comment: @matt please provide a code example.

Comment: Uh, `publisher1.subscribe(publisher2)`.

Comment: Oh, also please do note that none of your code is "real" since it never says `.store`. None of the pipelines you have shown would actually work.

Comment: What if `publisher1` is erased to any publisher? I've updated my question

Comment: Regarding the `store` - yes, true, but your idea is good.

Is it possible to use `subscribe` or something similar, but with the "source" publisher type erased?

Comment: You said they were passthrough subjects. Why would you erase that?

Comment: @matt I was able to the solution with your suggestion, I didn't notice the call order.
I called `publisher1.subscribe(publisher2)` and everything worked well, thank you! Feel free to post your solution as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I would just be repeating answers I've given before. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65386645/how-to-compose-a-combine-publisher-that-emits-the-last-emitted-value-to-its-2nd. I'm tempted to suggest your question is a duplicate.

Comment: Also I've explained all this for you at https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/publishers/publisherssubject.html

Comment: Thanks, great materials! I think it's still worth adding the answer, some people might search for this

Comment: Well, okay, findability is important.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a delightful feature of PassthroughSubject that it is both a publisher and an operator: a Subject can be chained *directly* to a pipeline.

So just say

```
publisher1.subscribe(publisher2)
```

and you're all set.